# Dropwizard postgres new connection per thread

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

Is there a configuration option in Dropwizard to make sure that each thread spawned by a new request to your service gets its own database connection?

Comment: I don't know Dropwizard, but you shouldn't create (and presumably close) a new connection for each thread. Make the framework use a connection pool where you can limit the maximum number of connections.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but if you use dbi.onDemand(MyDao.class) rather than dbi.open(MyDao.class) to create your, a new connection is opened for each call to a method in your Dao, and closed afterwards.